# Display a static Facebook login button image without using FBML

Tags: facebook

Is there a way or a link to a static image url to display the Facebook "Login with Facebook" button instead of the "Connect with Facebook" button? This seems to be the only link I can find for [Connect with Facebook](http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/fbconnect/login-buttons/connect_light_medium_long.gif). I am able to generate a "Login with Facebook" button using FBML markup fb:login_button but in this case, I'm generating a login url link (in order to direct user through to a touch-enabled Facebook login interface -display=touch).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found this image set very useful.

[social buttons as images](http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2009/06/sign-in-with-twitter-facebook-and-openid/)

Answer (score 10):

You can!

First, create the link you want.

```html
<a href="#" onclick="myfunc();">Login!</a>
```

Or you can use an image. They are floating around the web.

```html
<a href="#" onclick="myfunc();"><img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zB6N8/hash/4li2k73z.gif"></a>
```

Then, your `myfunc()` looks like this.

```js
function myfunc() {
  FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
      if (response.perms) {
        // user is logged in and granted some permissions.
        // perms is a comma separated list of granted permissions
      } else {
        // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions
      }
    } else {
      // user is not logged in
    }
  }, {perms:'offline_access,read_stream'});
}
```

Few more notes:

1. You will of course need the other standard Facebook setup, `FB.init()`, etc.
2. `onclick()` is of course bad Javascript. You can tidy up with jQuery or whatnot.
3. Foursquare does this and has a nice Facebook implementation. Pick it apart. Notice that unlike many other sites, you can log out of Foursquare without logging out of Facebook and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, there's no way.
You can only generate FB Login buttons with FBML and specifying a custom text. All static Facebook images use the words "Connect" instead of "Login".
I took a screenshot of the Login button instead :).